# How to get caller flow name in private flow in Mule

Tags: mule

I've a private flow which is shared by lot of public flows using `flow-ref`. I'm looking to get the caller flow name in private flow, using `MEL`, using Mule 3.3.0. Is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mule doesn't add any property to an event when it invokes a private flow via `flow-ref` so your options are:

- Use `<set-variable>` to set a variable with the flow name before calling the private flow and read this variable with `#[flowVars.yourVariableName]`.
- Use the inbound endpoint of the calling flow as the way to tell who's calling. You can get either the inbound endpoint URL with `#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_ENDPOINT]` or its name with `#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT]`.
- Create a custom [MessageProcessor](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/processor/MessageProcessor.html) that implements [FlowConstructAware](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/construct/FlowConstructAware.html): that way you'll get the flow name and will be able to automatically set it as an invocation variable on the `MuleEvent`'s message. Use this with a `custom-processor` element in all your parent flows, before the `flow-ref`.

Comment: David, this expression is throwing exception `<set-variable variableName="callerFlowName" value="#[flow.name]"/>`. Exception is: `1. unable to resolve token: unable to resolve variable 'flow' (org.mvel2.UnresolveablePropertyException)
  org.mvel2.integration.impl.BaseVariableResolverFactory:60 (null)
2. Execution of the expression "flow.name" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)`.            But this works fine: `<logger message="Flow name is #[flow.name]" level="INFO" />`

Comment: `#[flow.name]` is not valid: the `flow` variable is not an implicit top level variable in MEL - see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/MEL+Cheat+Sheet Again, Mule doesn't bind any variable with the flow name, you have to set it yourself: `<set-variable variableName="callerFlowName" value="myFlowName"/>`. I have added a third option BTW :)

Comment: I agree that flow is not a top level variable but when this statement worked: <logger message="Flow name is #[flow.name]" level="INFO" />, it made me try irrational stuff. Can you tell please why is #[flow.name] working with logger

Comment: Man, looking at the source code, it seems there **is** an undocumented MEL variable named `flow` but it's unclear when it gets bound and when not. Apparently in `logger` it is, but not in `set-variable`. Maybe you can try with an expression component: it may get bound so you could do: `flowVars.callerFlowName = flow.name` in the `expression-component`.